# Code fails when class definition closed

Tags: java, class, curly-braces, braces

I'm a beginner to Java trying to understand why my program works when it seems like it shouldn't. When I try and compile the code below, I get the error "class, interface, or enum expected" and it points to the brace on the final line of the program. If I remove the brace, the code compiles and then runs perfectly. But it seems to me that this brace should be necessary to close the definition of the class. Can anyone tell me what is going on? I am simply running the code from the terminal in a Linux environment. Thanks!

```
class Fermat 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    checkFermat(3,4,5,3);
  }
  public static void checkFermat(int a, int b, int c, int n) 
  {
    if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n) == Math.pow(c,n))
    {
      System.out.println("Fermat was wrong!");
    } 
      else 
      {
        System.out.println("Nope.");}
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Nope.");}` the curly brace there is closing the `else` branch, the `else branch` curly is closing the `checkFermat()` method, the `checkFermat()` curly brace is closing the `Fermat` class. This is a simple typographical error and should be closed as such... Protip: format your code before posting, you may identify problems more easily.

Comment: Oh right, thank you! This was the way I formatted it to make the braces easiest to read. Is there a better way?

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+F` or whichever your IDE's shortcut for codeformatting is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra unnecessary `}` in your app.
I thing you just put extra one at line `System.out.println("Nope.");}` Remove it  and the code will compile, making your IDE happy =)

Or remove any other closing `}` at the end of the program.

Comment: A missing or superfluous brace is a clear typo. We close such question.